# cakephp 3.0 Can an element have it's controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, element, cakephp-3.0

I have an element in 'src > Template > Element' called contact.ctp.

Is it possible for the 'contact.ctp' to have its own controller?

In 'src > Controller' I made an ElementController.php with a contact action inside it. Strange thing is that the functionality of sending an email doesn't work in this case

When I make a folder called Contact with inside a index.ctp file and in my controllers folder I make a ContactController.php with a index action inside it. Al the functionality in this case works.

Is it possible for elements to have their controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, elements can't have their own controller. But you can for e.g. set `$this->view = '/Element/contact';` in your controller action to make it use an element. Though in your particular case I don't see the benefit of using an element instead of regular action template.

You might also want to check out [View Cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) and [Forms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html).

Comment: I'm using an element because the contact Form returns on several pages and is not a page on it's own.

Comment: Thanks Admad. I used cells, the come in handy :) I'm just wondering if you can use  $this->Flash->success('We will get back to you soon.'); in a cell. Because it gives me this error: Call to a member function success() on null